# Not able to add iPhone in Appium Studio

Tags: ios, iphone, automation, appium, seetest

While trying to add an iPhone in Appium Studio and after login when we click on Register button, then it says account added. But "OK" button remains disable.

[image]

[image]

Any help will be much appreciated, earlier (6-7 months back) we used to do the same with no issues. Not sure what got change now.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issues:
1.Installed older version of Appium studio (AppiumStudio_windows-x32_22_6_8829.exe) and signed into the apple developer account and added the device
2.Later uninstalled the application from Apps & features list
3.Install the new version of Appium studio (AppiumStudio_windows-x32_22_8_8881.exe) and connect the iPhone device,'OK' button was enabled

NOTE:I have tried on trial and error basis , this step worked for me, not followed any sites

Comment: Which versions did you used. I am on latest version 22.8.8881 which is having issue. Previous versions not allowed me to log in.